# What strings does this language accept/reject?

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata

```
F = {ww | w ∈ {0,1}^*}
```

Which strings are accepted and why?

1. 0011
2. 1010
3. 1111

Comment: A language is a set of strings. A language "accepts" a string if the string belongs to the language.

Comment: Which of your three strings can be written in the form $ww$ for some $w$? This is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Though the hint has been provided in the comment section, Here is the answer too:

F accepts strings of form ww.

1. No, there is no way you can write it in the form of ww.
2. Yes. w=10
3. Yes. w=11